# why is my LESSCSS not working

Tags: html, css, less

Please can you tell me why this LESSCSS is not working?
The H2 is not changing color?

Thanks

StyleSheet2.less

```
@color: blue;

#header {
  color: @color;
}
h2 {
  color: @color;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="_/css/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="_/script/JavaScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="_/css/StyleSheet2.less"> 
    <script src="_/script/less-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>





<!-- css3-mediaqueries.js for IE less than 9 -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


</head>
<body>
    <div>


        <div id="bodyDiv">
            a<br />
            a<br />
            a<br />
            a<br />
            a<br />
            a<br />
            a<br />
            a<br />
            a<br />
            a<br />
            a<br />
            <h2>test</h2>a<br />
            a<br />

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: the H2 is not changing color

Comment: LessCSS needs to be compiled into an ordinary CSS file. Have you verified that this worked? Better check the contents of the CSS file that to see if something changes on the page.

Comment: ok in your console log there is some error?

Comment: the documentation saifd the less.js file and my style.less file  - is that correct?

Comment: GolezTrol - do I have to compile it first? does it not do it automatically?

Comment: Does it work when you try a normal (CSS-like) `color` declaration for `H2`?

Comment: Sorry, I see that you are using a client side parser. I don't know about this one. So never mind my remark about compilation. I would consider using a server side LESS compiler (LessPHP for instance), that can precompile and cache your CSS files, so you don't have to bother the browser with it for each request.

Answer (score 1):

Your less file is syntactically correct, you have the correct order of the less stylesheet and script, and your console shows no errors, so unless you have javascript disabled for some reason, the error must be in `_/css/StyleSheet1.css` where you probably define a color for your `h2` element with [higher precendence](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) than the rule you specified in your less stylesheet. Remove that rule or give the rule in your less stylesheet higher precedence (e.g. `#bodyDiv h2{}`) to solve that problem.